# Moto X wont connect to Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, android, mtp

I have a Nexus 5 which when I connect it via USB works perfectly as far as transferring files goes. But as soon as I plug in the Moto X it acts like it doesn't exist. Reminiscent of an Ex-girlfriend of mine.

I've downloaded multiple programs and none of them seem to do anything. (qlix, gmtp, etc.)

Phone is set to MTP and is running android 4.4

Answer (score 1):

Many people have found luck mounting Android 4.x devices using Go-MTP.

Here is how you can add it and give it a try.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install go-mtpfs
sudo apt-get install go-mtpfs-unity
```

After that you can watch this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pelKv939N8) for more instructions.

You can also try:

```
 sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that but it gave me errors, 404 not found, failed to fetch, unable to locate package. I dont know what I'm doing wrong. Is there some other program I have to have installed before I do all that?

Comment: Can you paste the full error at paste.ubuntu.com please?

Comment: yup I just did it. It wasnt able to locate the go-mtpfs file

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6718862/